# Como faço para converter um arquivo de backup do SQL Server em .BAK para .CSV?

Tags: sql

O arquivo foi gerado a partir do SQL Server. Gostaria de converte-lo em um arquivo visual, tipo .CSV, é possível?

Comment: Cara, não sei o propósito disso, mas você pode exportar os dados das suas tabelas para um arquivo TXT usando um dos recursos do próprio MSSQL: tarefas + gerar scripts. Um outro modo para isso é criar uma ferramenta que lê sua tabela e escreve em TXT os dados num arquivo. Atente-se para a quantidades de registros nas tabelas. Se for o caso, separe os arquivos por data!

Answer (score 1):

Cara, esse tipo de conversão não rola, por que o arquivo BAK do sql, na verdade são instruções nativas SQL como criação das tabelas, inserts, etc..

Comment: teria que instalar o SQL Server e visualizar la mesmo né?

Comment: Isso mesmo, instalar o SQL, restaurar a base, dai você poderá visualizar.

Comment: @IvanTeles Quem sabe adicionar na sua resposta essa ideia de restaurar a base. Fica melhor do que "[...]não rola"

Answer (score 0):

## Entendendo o arquivo .BAK

O arquivo .BAK é um arquivo de ponto de restauração do sistema. Ele permite que você restaure **tudo** no seu banco de dados.

Para entender o que é um banco de dados, recomendo a leitura [desta resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/191218/64969).

### Sistemas gerenciadores de bancos de dados

Os famosos SGBDs. Eles permitem que você trabalhe com o banco de dados de maneira uniforme. Se não fosse por eles, você teria uma estrutura proprietária em um arquivo, muitas vezes com capacidade especializada.

Eles permitem que você coloque informações generalizadas neles. Em um esquema relacional, como são os bancos que falam SQL, existe [todo um estudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization?wprov=sfsi1) para deixar seus dados normalizados. Você não precisaria seguir essas normalizações, mas Codd demonstrou que as formas normais facilitam na manutenção das estruturas.

Para saber manipular os dados, um banco precisa saber informações sobre esses dados: os metadados das tabelas e colunas. Então, para que haja leitura eficaz e real dos dados cujas estruturas não são definidas a priori, é necessário saber encontrar esses metadados para saber como ler os dados.

### Além da estrutura

O SQL Server permite fazer diversas coisas além de simplesmente armazenar dados em estruturas arbitrárias. Existem também limitações/constraints. Elas podem ser de múltiplos tipos, como unicidade na tabela, chave estrangeiras de outra, não nula, valores em um conjunto limitado.

Além dessas restrições, também temos gatilhos. Gatilhos servem para várias coisas interessantes, como manter o sistema coerente ou atualizar o banco com novas informações ao chegar uma outra.

Também temos procedimentos para manipulação do banco definidos pelo usuário. E também funções, que processam dados em outros dados.

Além disso, para permitir uma leitura mais eficiente da base de dados, existem índices, que são dados sobre os dados informando mais ou menos como eles estão dispostos no arquivo físico para poder procurar de maneira eficiente.

Depois de tudo isso, temos as `views`. De começo, as views são dados já pré-selecionados através de uma consulta. Para deixar a situação interessante, views permitem toda a DML tradicional, como seleção, inserção, atualização e deleção. Devido a essa capacidade de ter os dados alterados, views podem ter gatilhos, assim como tabelas. Se não bastassem os gatilhos, às vezes consultar uma view acaba sendo dispendioso, então pode-se criar um índice para ela! Nesse caso, a view se torna materializada no banco: as informações não são mais simplesmente resgatadas das tabelas originais, mas sim de dados escritos no arquivo que foram obtidos através dessas tabelas originais.

## Extraindo os dados

Você deseja extrair os dados, não é mesmo? Para tal, é primeiro preciso remover tudo que não é dado nem metadado do arquivo, assim como possivelmente os dados de views materializadas, para ler apenas aquilo que interessa. Depois de fazer essa separação, você precisará entender como se lê o metadado da tabela, para então começar a resgatar cada linha individualmente. Não se esqueça também que dados inteiros são armazenados de modo binário, então eu não armazena 123456 em 7 caracteres, mas em 4 bytes (se for do tipo inteiro). Você precisará se lembrar de ler o binário para produzir o texto do CSV

Além disso, não se esqueça: possivelmente todas as informações do arquivo podem estar compactadas, em um padrão que você precisará pesquisar para ver qual é. E também, para evitar alguns comportamentos indesejados, muitas vezes o banco de dados larga no arquivo trechos abandonados de propósito, não vem ao escopo desta resposta falar detalhadamente sobre essa estratégia no armazenamento.

Mas você tem alguém que já faz esse trabalho todo para você. É o próprio SQL Server. Se quiser minimizar seu trabalho, faça como o Ivan Teles sugeriu [en sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/72682/64969) e restaure a base. Se você quiser ter um trabalho um pouquinho maior (mentindo, seria **muito** maior), você pode tentar ir atrás de alguma documentação oficial da MicroSoft explicando como ela almoça os dados dentro do .BAK, que eu não creio ser uma informação fácil e simples de achar.