# O que caracteriza um banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia

O que faz uma coleção de dados ser chamada de banco de dados?

Por exemplo, se eu tenho um arquivo `pessoas.txt` da seguinte maneira:

```
Vinicius
João
Maria
José
```

E passo a escrever, ler e atualizar os dados ali, ele é considerado um banco de dados?

Já vi também desenvolvedores armazenarem dados em XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?> 
<Pessoa>
    <Codigo>1</Codigo> 
    <Nome>Vinicius</Nome> 
</Pessoa>
```

Ou até um arquivo CSV. De fato, existem diversas maneiras de armazenar dados, porém seria considerado **banco de dados** somente aqueles arquitetados em tecnologias como SQL, MariaDB, MySQL, etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esta não é uma definição simples, qualquer uma pode dar margem a entender uma coisa diferente do que é. E sem uma definição clara não é fácil definir o que é. Darei minha definição.

Um banco de dados é uma coleção de dados diversos que pode ser facilmente organizada de diversas formas e ter sua recuperação de dados fácil e rápida. Deve haver um mecanismo que facilite isto, não pode ser só dados organizados.

Apenas um simples CSV ou XML permite isto? Me parece que não. Um mecanismo um pouco mais sofisticado talvez já possa ser considerado um banco de dados (uma planilha Excel por exemplo). Provavelmente seria um ruim, mas seria. Um formato assim poderia ser usado para o armazenamento básico, ainda que ineficiente e não atender todos cenários, mas não é porque tem um arquivo assim que já é um banco de dados.

Então o banco de dados não pode ser um único arquivo de dados simples (até pode ser algo mais sofisticado em apenas um arquivo), mas um mecanismo que obtenha organização e acesso rápido em **dados diversos** usando um arquivo texto simples já é um banco de dados. Note que sequer há a exigência da escrita ser rápida ou ser permanente, estas podem ser características de um modelo específico de banco de dados.

Um banco de dados não precisa usar SQL, tão pouco precisa ser relacional. Ser relacional é apenas um modelo. SQL é só uma opção da manipulação de dados relacionais.

Informalmente quando as pessoas falam de banco de dados quase sempre estão falando de algo relacional com SQL. Mais recentemente o NoSQL (péssimo nome) começou ser usado também, embora sua [adoção seja maior do que a real necessidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122452/101).

Nem vou referenciar a Wikipedia porque tanto em português quanto em inglês a definição é ruim que dói, os artigos são uns *frankensteins*.

É muito comum encontrar material que define o que é banco de dados como sendo apenas o banco de dados relacional típico, ignoram que algo mais simples também é banco de dados. Por isso é muito complicado usar uma referência canônica. Há também quem ache que mesmo um arquivo texto simples é um banco de dados.

E não deveria causar espanto porque já vi muita gente falando besteira, e quando isso acontece é porque não tem uma forma definição mais formal. Por isso que bancos relacionais acabam sendo melhor, há definição mais formal, quando alguém falar besteira é fácil mostrar que ela está errada, e aí só resta ela continuar com teimosia ou aceitar o erro. Onde não tem uma definição formal cada um fala uma coisa e todo mundo pode, ou não, estar certo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Devo discordar de XML não ser considerado como formato válido para banco de dados. Lembro de estudar bancos de dados hierárquicos como projeto de pesquisa para um professor na faculdade. Como eu não lembro a referência original disso, achei um outro pouco disso na internet: [wiki c2](http://wiki.c2.com/?HierarchicalDatabase), sempre acho divertido a discussão nesse site; [sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/). Sobre ser rápido e fácil, isso é um efeito desejável, não primário, no meu entendimento

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado acho que você não leu com atenção porque eu falei justamente que o XML pode ser um formato usado, não pode ser o banco de dados. Pela sua definição qualquer coisa que tenha dados é um banco de dados, não sei porque deveria existir um termo para isto, afinal "dados" seria suficiente. Se puder definir melhor o que é banco de dados para você, seria bom.

Comment: reli algumas vezes sua resposta nesse trecho, continuei no mesmo entendimento. Definição de banco de dados seria um conjunto não atômico de dados, e um sistema gerenciador de banco de dados é algo que forneça um mecanismo de leitura/escrita sobre o banco de dados. Assim, o banco de dados e o sistema gerenciador de banco de dados são indissociáveis. Eu sei que é um tanto vago, mas é essa a definição que tenho em mente, principalmente levando em consideração os diversos tipos de base de dados (hierárquico, chave-valor, tuplas, etc)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado exatamente, isto não quer dizer nada e pode ser usado pra um monte coisa que ninguém ousaria chamar de banco de dados.

Comment: Aurélio Verde discorda sobre "ninguém ousar": https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.novatec.com.br/sumarios/sumario-9788575221525.pdf ; capítulo 10: bancos de dados textuais ;-)

Comment: Só vi um índice, não algum texto que indique algo.

Comment: a ideia era exemplificar que o Aurélio teve a ousadia de caracterizar bancos de dados textuais com shell script (tuplas em csv, se não me engano em múltiplos arquivos de tabelas). Infelizmente, não achei o livro dele na internet

Comment: Achei o código do capítulo no GitHub: https://github.com/aureliojargas/livro-shell/blob/master/10-banco/

Comment: Eu vou encerrar porque senti que vamos ficar em círculos, o que você mostrou não tem nada a ver com o início da conversa, eu estou falando de laranjas e você de alfaces. Tudo o que você falou e mostrou comprovam o que eu disse na resposta, suas conclusões são diferentes.

Answer (score 5):

**Banco de Dados**, como o próprio nome sugere, é uma estrutura organizada, capaz de reter informações, e permitir que esta mesma informação seja recuperada, fornecendo mecanismos específicos capazes de dinamizar a tarefa, tornando eficiente, e seguro o armazenamento/recuperação dos dados/informação nele contidos - *ou simplesmente colecção organizada de dados capazes de se relacionar, de modo a torna-los mais consistentes para determinadas tarefas?*.

O que faz uma colecção de dados ser chamada de banco de dados, é a sua estrutura organizacional. O banco de dados agrupa os dados em blocos específicos, de modo que cheguem a ser possuidores de características próprias - *já imaginaste o que seria tentar encontrar alguém sem nome, rosto, no meio de uma multidão com as mesmas características?*

Um arquivo de texto simples (`.txt`, ou outro qualquer) pode ou não ser considerado um banco de dados, mas muito depende da forma como vais ordenar/agrupar a informação que lá estiver, ou mesmo propósito a que se destina a informação lá contida.

Bancos de dados, são normalmente caracterizados, por possuírem uma estrutura sólida, bem delineada e organizada, fácil acesso, recuperação e discriminação da informação neles contidos, <strike>e acima de tudo por serem seguros, senão todos nós estaríamos a usar ficheiros `xml` para armazenar senhas.</strike>

Alguns comentários/ideias vão obviamente discordar, e com razão digo, mas é o que é, **banco** (instituições financeiras mesmo) são assim denominados porque cumprem com algumas, senão grande parte, das características aqui mencionadas. <strike>Se não fossem seguros, e capazes de agilizar alguma operações com o dinheiro, melhor seria se estivéssemos a usar latas para guardar dinheiro, ou andar com milhões na carteira</strike>. Por esta razão quando se fala de **banco de dados** vem-nos a cabeça estes sistemas de armazenamento já muito conhecidos.

Edit: a segurança não é de todo uma característica fundamental para caracterizar um banco de dados.

Comment: De fato a segurança não é inerente ao banco de dados, inclusive a maioria deles são inseguros por padrão, nem consigo me lembrar de algum diferente disto.

Comment: @bigown pois é, não tanto, mas é de facto uma componente para a caracterização de banco de dados.

Comment: Galera, discutir conceito sem referência bibliográfica, puro empirismo. Mas não confunda os seus tipos de bancos que pode ser relacional SGDB, pode ser simples um Mapa de dados;  Ou simplesmente um txt; Um banco de dados é uma coleção de dados guardadas; A forma como vai ser gerenciado são seus tipos.

https://books.google.com.br/books?hl=pt-BR&lr=&id=xBeO9LSlK7UC&oi=fnd&pg=PP23&dq=banco+de+dados+defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o+&ots=xbMDj1Ba3M&sig=5mf2OpYhIdvZuUtsvORYHzLGR0E#v=onepage&q=banco%20de%20dados%20defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o&f=false

Esse livro é uma boa referência.

Comment: @alxwca valeu por não acrescentar nada novo.