# O que é um banco de dados? Para que serve?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Estou ensaiando os estudos em sistemas de informação e estou curioso sobre o assunto!

Comment: Removi a ultima pergunta para não tornar a pergunta fora do escopo, apesar de achar que já responderam aqui, se achar, posto.

Comment: Qual e especificamente a sua duvida sobre banco de dados? Se for desde o começo, ai se torna bem ampla, se bem que acho que da pra dar uma resposta canônica. [Um ponto de partida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/banco-de-dados/info)

Comment: Mas exatamente o que você não entendeu? Quero dizer creio ser meio que intuitivo, banco é um lugar para guardar coisas, tem banco de sangue, aonde guardam sangue, banco de leite aonde guardam leite para crianças que não podem ser amamentadas, etc. Então banco de dados é aonde guardamos dados, certo? Teria alguma duvida especifica?

Comment: [O que caracteriza um banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191199/91)

Comment: Banco de dados são conjuntos de informações organizadas e relacionadas, formados por colunas e linhas. As colunas são chamadas de campos, por exemplo, é tudo aquilo que será pedido ao usuário, como: nome, endereço, telefone. As linhas são chamadas de registros, informações dadas pelo usuário, por exemplo: João Paulo, Rua 1, 33227788.

Para substituir as velhas fichas como do dentista, da locadora, etc, surgiram os bancos de dados, já que era grande o gasto de tempo para preencher e até para localizar. Saiba mais em https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banco_de_dados

Comment: Se não for isso que quer saber, deixe a pergunta mais específica para entender a real necessidade.